# Is it possible to handle USB connection from PC to my WindowsPhone?

Tags: windows-phone-8

A question to Microsoft guys :)

Let's imagine that I connected WindowsPhone to PC via USB and launched some application. For this application, is it possible to listen for connections that can come from PC?

I want to send requests from PC via USB and handle them by WindowsPhone app.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 does not have any USB communication protocol which is accessible to SDK applications.

This is unlike Windows Phone 7 that had some support over TCP/IO networks.

You can of course communicate over Bluetooth, or connect the two devices to the same WiFi network and communicate over that.

[Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/82d9aa7a-50f9-4471-8598-8cb9001e7962/usb-port-communication-api-between-windows-8-and-windows-phone8?forum=wptools).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Well, it seems I have to wait until WindowsPhone devices evolve a bit more :)